# Run shell script inside Angular app packaged in Electron

Tags: angular, shell, electron

I have Angular 2 app packaged in Electron. I wonder if it is possible to run shell script from that app.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993447/how-to-run-requireexpress-from-a-typescript-angular-component-in-electron-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to achieve that using **ngx-childprocess**

**In 3 steps:**

1. in your electron/angular app install **ngx-childprocess**

   ```
   yarn add ngx-childprocess
   or
   npm install ngx-childprocess --save
   ```
2. add **gx-childprocess** into **app.module**

   ```
   imports: [
       NgxChildProcessModulem
       ....
   ```
3. run the script (in this case I am running java jar)

   ```
   import { ChildProcessService } from 'ngx-childprocess';
   ... 
   export class AppComponent {

      constructor(private childProcessService: ChildProcessService) {
           console.log('isElectronApp ' + childProcessService.isElectronApp);
           let options: string[] = [];
           childProcessService.childProcess.exec('java -jar child-process-test-1.0.jar', 
                                                 options,
                                                 (data) => {console.log(data);});
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: The callback arrow function you use as the third parameter of childProcessService.childProcess.exec function has to specify all three 'err', 'stdout' and 'stderr' (or whichever name you choose) to get the output of the script in the second one. If you use a single one (data), as it was before the edit, you get only null if the script has been successfully run. But most of us are interested in the output of the script, so that's why we have to specify all three and consider/read the second for example if you want to see the output of the script in stdout.

Comment: hi,is there any way to run .bat file using ngx-childprocess??