# How to run require("express"); from a TypeScript Angular Component in Electron App

Tags: angular, typescript, express, electron

I'm new to "Angular", "typescript" and "Electron". I created a "server.js" file with the [basic example of express](http://expressjs.com/es/starter/hello-world.html). What is the correct way to create a local server for the local network?

I  want to create an "Angular" "Electron" App with a button to run the express server, but I don't know what to code in order to execute the "server.js" file.

```
function runLocalServer() {

  servidor = require('server.js');  // This line is a error!

  ....
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail as to what your Electron app is trying to achieve, what the directory structures are, and what errors you're getting?

Comment: Sorry, I just want to know how run require() from "typescript" in my Angular app inside Electron to run express. I don't know if I 'am clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript accepts a normal `require()` as well as the `import` syntax. For example:

```
const express = require('express');
// OR
import * as express from 'express';
```